# Understanding different monadic and applicative binds/combinators in the context of a data type constructor?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, applicative

I've been given the following piece of code, which I am trying to get my head around:

```
data MyExample e i = MyExample (CustomMonad e i)
   | forall b. MyExample e b :>>= (b -> CustomMonad e b)
   | forall b. (MyExample e (b -> a)) :<*> (MyExample e b)
   | forall b. (b -> a) :<$> (MyExample e b)
```

1) What do `:>>=`, `:<*>` and `:<$>` do differently, as opposed to

Monadic bind `>>=`

```
exampleFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int
exampleFunction el = Just (el + 100)
main = do 
  result <- exampleFunction >>= exampleFunction 21
```

Applicative combinators `<*>` and `<$>`

```
exampleFunction :: Int -> Maybe Int
exampleFunction el = Just el
main = do 
 result <- pure exampleFunction <$> (+) <*> (ExampleType 2) <*> (ExampleType 4)
```

2)  Am I right in saying the following:

a) `MyExample (CustomMonad e i)` is constructing the `CustomMonad` type with e and i, then wrapping this in the `MyExample` context?

b) `forall b. MyExample e b :>>= (b -> CustomMonad e b)` is taking a `(MyExample e i)` then taking b and inputting this into a function (`b -> CustomMonad e b`) that constructs a `(CustomMonad e b)`?

c) `forall b. (MyExample e (b -> a)) :<*> (MyExample eb)` is taking a `MyExample` constructed with a value `e` and a function `(b -> a)` and perform *some kind* of applicative combinator operation with a `MyExample e b`?

d) `forall b. (b -> a) :<$> (MyExample e b)` is passing some result from `(MyExample e b)` to a function `(b -> a)`

Additionally, am I right in saying the use of `forall b` is ensuring that `b` is the same type throughout the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:>>=` doesn't actually do anything with its arguments; it simply creates a new value of type `MyExample e i` that you could later *interpret* as a call to `>>=`, but you could do practically anything you want with it using a different interpreter.